# високосный год джаваскрипт

Tags: javascript

Где тут может быть ошибка ? в джаве когда старался изучить точно так делал (ну кроме ===)  все работало

```js
let year = 2000;
if (year%400 ===0 ){
   console.log(year + ' год - високосный');
  return;
}

 if  (year % 100 === 0 ) {
    console.log(year + ' год - невисокосный');
   return;
} 
if (year %4 ===0){
  console.log(year + ' год - високосный');
return;
}
else {
    console.log(year + 'год — невисокосный');
}
```

Comment: сейчас _"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement",_ потому что return вне функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если год не делится на 4, значит он обычный.

Иначе надо проверить не делится ли год на 100.

Если не делится, значит это не столетие и можно сделать вывод, что год високосный.

Если делится на 100, значит это столетие и его следует проверить его делимость на 400.

Если год делится на 400, то он високосный.
https://taskcode.ru/if/year

```js
const getLeapYear = year => year % 4 === 0 && (year % 100 !== 0 || year % 400 === 0);
console.log(getLeapYear(2000))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let year = 1900;
let leap;
 
if (year % 400 == 0)
  leap = true;
else if (year % 100 == 0)
  leap = false;
else if (year % 4 == 0)
  leap = true;
else
  leap = false;

console.log(year + ' год — ' + (leap? '' : 'не') + 'високосный');
```